# Are there any contexts when specified WebView panel is active in VSCode extension keybinding contribution points?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I saw the [when-clause-contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) document but I can't find something like that... Is there any conditions WebView panel is active or alternatives?

I'm now making copy & paste feature in my extension but if `when` is not specified, some default keybindings may be blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a generic context key for when a webview is active. However using the `setContext` command, you can create a custom context that tracks just when one of your webviews is active

Here's what VS code's markdown preview (which also uses a webview) does to create a custom context key that is set when the preview is active:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/cd7c7c5fa2c16c6e8281436c35e9a7709cfbd89d/extensions/markdown-language-features/src/features/previewManager.ts#L152

Answer (score 2):

I believe this new context value is what you need:

##### New activeWebviewPanelId context key

The new `activeWebviewPanelId` context key tracks the `viewType` of the currently focused webview panel. You can use it in when clauses to enable commands or menu items when your webview is focused

```
"when": "activeWebviewPanelId == 'markdown.preview'"
```

from [v1.71 Release Notes: active webview panel context key](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#new-activewebviewpanelid-context-key)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, webviewId did not work.